# How to get associated product name in list.phtml file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am new in magento2.
I am stuck on a single problem since 3 day's and not a sing solution worked for me.
I am unable to get the associated product name in list.phtml file.
I have 2 associated product with a group product. I am able to get Group product name but unable to get associated product name.
Here is my code of list.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped

 */
?>
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('seachbar-blockbanner')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php

$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$block->setPreconfiguredValue();
$_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); 
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0;
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_optionHelper = $this->helper('Codazon\ThemeOptions\Helper\Data');
$_mobileHelper = $this->helper('Codazon\ThemeOptions\Helper\Mobile');
$labelHelper = $this->helper('Codazon\ProductLabel\Helper\Data');
echo $_product;

?>
<?php


foreach ($_productCollection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}  
?>

 <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts){
         foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item){
             echo 'Name  =  '.$_item->getName().'<br>';
                          echo $_item->getName();
                          echo"MY Name is Abhishek";


        }}
             ?>


<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php //echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    $showHover = $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/hover_product_effect');
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $image_hover = 'category_page_grid_hover';
        $showDescription = $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/show_short_description');
        $showCompareWishlist = $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/show_action');
        $showReviewRating = $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/review_rating_star');
        $pageColumn = $_optionHelper->getPageColumns();
        switch ($pageColumn) {
            case '3columns':
                $columnsDeskClass = 'desktop_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_desktop_view/product_row_desk_3col');
                $columnsTabClass = 'tablet_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_tablet_view/product_row_tablet_3col');
                break;
            case '1column':
                $columnsDeskClass = 'desktop_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_desktop_view/product_row_desk_1col');
                $columnsTabClass = 'tablet_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_tablet_view/product_row_tablet_1col');
                break;
            case '2columns':
                $columnsDeskClass = 'desktop_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_desktop_view/product_row_desk_2col');
                $columnsTabClass = 'tablet_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_tablet_view/product_row_tablet_2col');
                break;
            default:
                $columnsDeskClass = 'desktop_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_desktop_view/product_row_desk_2col');
                $columnsTabClass = 'tablet_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_tablet_view/product_row_tablet_2col');
                break;
        }
        //echo $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_desktop_view/product_row_desk_2col');
        //echo $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_desktop_view/product_row_desk_1col');
        //echo $columnsDeskClass;
        $columnsMobileClass = 'mobile_' . $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/category_mobile_view/product_row_mobile');
        if (!$_mobileHelper->isMobile()) {
            $columnsClass = $columnsDeskClass;
        } else if ($_mobileHelper->isTablet()) {
            $columnsClass = $columnsTabClass;
        } else if ($_mobileHelper->isMobile() && !$_mobileHelper->isTablet()) {
            $columnsClass = $columnsMobileClass;
        }
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $image_hover = 'category_page_list_hover';
        $showDescription = $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/show_short_description');
        ;
        $showCompareWishlist = $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/show_action');
        $showReviewRating = $_optionHelper->getConfig('general_section/category_view/review_rating_star');
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
        $columnsClass = 'desk_1';
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
        <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $columnsClass ?>" id="category-products-grid">
            <ol class="products list items product-items same-height">
                <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
                <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                    <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">                   
                        <div class="cdz-hover-section">
                            <div class="cdz-product-top">
                                <?php

                                $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                                $productHoverImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image_hover);
                                if ($pos != null) {
                                    $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;' . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                                }
                                ?>
                                <?php // Product Image ?>
                                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                                    <span class="main-image">
                                        <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="hover-image">
                                        <?php echo $productHoverImage->toHtml(); ?>
                                        <span class="product-arrow"><img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/green.png'); ?>" /></span>
                                    </span>

                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!--wishlist-->
                            <!--<div class="cdz-product-wishlist show-tooltip">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && $showCompareWishlist): ?>
                                                                <a href="#"
                                                                   class="action towishlist"
                                                                   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                                                   aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                                                   data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                                                   data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                                                   role="button">
                                                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                                                </a>
                            <?php endif; ?> 
                    </div>-->                                   
                            <?php $labelHelper->showLabel($_product) ?>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="product details product-item-details">
                            <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                            ?>
                            <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                <a class="product-item-link"
                                   href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                       <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                </a>
                            </strong>
                            <div class="short_description_content">
                                <?php //echo substr($_product->getShortDescription(),0,80); ?>
                            </div>


                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ // echo $block->getProductPrice($_product)  ?>
                            <?php if ($showReviewRating): ?>
                                <?php //echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?> 
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>

                            <div class="product-item-inner">
                                    <!--<div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                            <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>

                                            </div>
                                            <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>-->
                                <?php if ($showDescription): ?>
                                    <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo substr($_product->getShortDescription(),0,80); ?>
                                        <!--<a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                           class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo __('Learn More') ?></a>-->
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                                <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                         <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>


                            <!--quiclick-addtocart-->
                             <div class="cdz-product-bottom <?php echo $showHover ? 'hover-effect' : 'non-hover' ?>">
                                    <div class="cdz-buttons-container">
                                    <div class="cdz-buttons-inner">                             
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <!--<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                                class="action tocart primary show-tooltip">
                                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                        </form>-->



                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                         <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?> 




                            <?php echo $this->helper('Codazon\QuickShop\Helper\Data')->getQuickShopButton($_product, 'show-tooltip'); ?>
                            <?php
                            $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
                            ?>
                            <?php if ($showCompareWishlist): ?>
                                                                <a href="#"
                                                                   class="action tocompare show-tooltip"
                                                                   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                                                   aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                                                   data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                                                   role="button">
                                                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="quantity" style="float:right; width:60%;">
                                <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
<input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty form-control"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
<!--button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>" class="action btn-add-cart tocart"-->
<!--i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
<span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
</button-->
</form>
</div>                         
               <div class="weight-box">

    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="price">
            </div>
        <span class="weight">3KG</span>
            <div class="wbox">
        <span class="wprice"><span class="old">$1700</span><span class="new">$1500</span></span>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span class="wplush">+</span></a>
            </div>
</li>

<li>
<span class="weight">12KG</span>
            <div class="wbox">
        <span class="wprice"><span class="old">$1700</span><span class="new">$1500</span></span>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span class="wplush">+</span></a>
            </div>
</li>

    </ul>
    </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="bottom-view-more" style="width:95%;">
        <a href="<?php //echo $this->getLimitUrl('all') ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo __('View more') ?></a>
    </div>-->
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml()  ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
            }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getMode() == 'grid'): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(['jquery'], function ($) {
                function setClass() {
                    var widthWindow = $(window).width();
                    var list = $('#category-products-grid');
                    if (widthWindow > 1200)
                        list.removeClass().addClass('<?php echo $columnsDeskClass ?>');
                    else if (widthWindow > 768)
                        list.removeClass().addClass('<?php echo $columnsTabClass ?>');
                    else
                        list.removeClass().addClass('<?php echo $columnsMobileClass ?>');
                }
                $(window).on('resize', function () {
                    setClass();
                });
                setClass();
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<style>
  .qs-button{
    width: 100% !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #ec9315 !important;
    border-color: #ec9315 !important;
  }
 .qs-button:hover{ background-color: #ec9315; border-color: #ec9315;}
  .qs-button:before{ content:none; }

</style>
```

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is working for me:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
    $grouped = $_product->load($_product->getId());                       
    $associatedProducts = $grouped->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($grouped);
    foreach ($associatedProducts as $product):
        echo $product->getName();
    endforeach;
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: @shweta If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.